# Agrupe os textFieds à direita no JasperSoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Eu quero agrupar meus textFields todos os direitos para que eles possam formar os dias de um calendário de aulas, mas nem todos esses dias têm aulas e eu quero omitir os dias que não ocorreram as aulas, fazendo com que seja alinhado à direita da minha página. sendo agrupados nos meses em que as aulas aconteceram e nos dias de aula ...

Exemplo no mês de abril: 01 (quinta-feira), 02 (sexta-feira), 03 (sábado), 04 (domingo), 05 (segunda-feira);

```
| fieldName | fieldName2 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |
```

Quero exibir apenas os dias 01, 02 e 05, mantendo o alinhamento de todos os direitos.

```
| fieldName | fieldName2 | --space que envia e agrupa a direita -> | 01 | 02 | 05 |
```

agrupando à direita e omitindo os dias 03 e 04.

mantendo todos alinhados lado a lado nos dias em que as aulas aconteceram

Comment: ja tentou usar uma regra condicional para formatação em caso de feriados a fonte do seu texto fica-se branco ? Ou Usar a configuração do componente chamada "print when" essa voce informa uma condicional se verdadeiro o componente aparece caso não ele nao ira aparecer.

Comment: sim, eu faço isso, eles aparecem ou somem conforme a condição, o meu problema é que eles não se agrupam a direita.